# How to call one Javascript function on different places in one amp HTML document using ID or Class?

Tags: javascript, amp-html

//Called add to cart to perform action on  this id

```
<amp-script script="addToCart" target="amp-script" data-ampdevmode>
               <button id="bottomSheetView" on="tap:AMP.setState({productId:{id : {{id}}}})" class="btn btn-block btn-sm btn-view">add</button>
</amp-script>
```

//I want to append result in this amp script container or add any div in this container but
script will remain same addToCart

```
<amp-script layout="container" script="addToCart" data-ampdevmode>
    
</amp-script>

<script id="addToCart" type="text/plain" target="amp-script">
    let bottomSheetView = document.getElementById("bottomSheetView");
    if(bottomSheetView)
    {
        bottomSheetView.addEventListener("click",createBottomSheet);
    }
    async function createBottomSheet() {enter code here
        let productId = JSON.parse(await AMP.getState('productId.id'));
        AMP.setState({bottomSheet:false});
        console.log(productId);
    }
</script>


<amp-state id="productId">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
        "id" : ""
    }
  </script>
</amp-state>
```

Comment: What does the console say? Do you have a value for `<meta name="amp-script-src"
    content=`